# Animation Rendering Issues

Tags: rendering, animation

I am currently trying to render my first animated workpiece and I am having two primary issues with making it work. I should start by saying that although I'm relatively new to Blender as a whole, up to this point, I have done many still picture renders before this and I have yet to have any issues with the rendering process, be it Eevee or Cycles.

The issues with animation rendering that I am having are:

- Crashing: I am getting frequent crashing with I try to render the animation. When I hit the "Render Animation" button, Blender appears to render the first 1 or 10 frames and then immediately closes without even giving an error report or anything. This occurs for me when rendering in both Eevee and Cycles and when I try to render either as a video or as an image set. The problem is oddly inconsistent, as maybe once in every 10 or so tries, the render will fully go through and finish (usually when rendering as a video output, I have yet to finish any renders with the output to image set).

I've already checked my tmp folder permissions and I've tried rendering to a custom folder as well, with seemingly indistinguishable changes in results. Something to note is that I can run a "Viewport Render" with 100% success, the render finishes and saves perfectly.

- Body Animation Not playing During Render: In the occasions that the render does successfully finish (the full render, not the viewport render), the character's keyed motions do not play in the render, but the camera's keyed motions will. It's as if the character is stuck in the posing position of the current viewport frame for the entire sequence with the camera going about the intended keyed motion sequences.

Similar to my crashing issues, if I run a "Viewport Render" the sequence will render perfectly with all my keyed motions behaving as expected.

---

Specs:

- Windows 10
- Blender 2.83.3
- AMD R7 2700X
- 16 GB RAM (2100 Mhz)
- Zotac GTX 1070 Ti (8GB GDDR5 version)
- All hardware running as base/stock speeds

[For reference, here is the .blend file that I am working with.](https://drive.google.com/file/d/1Ni2oMjd1V04m4LCS4osZWG2ssXdXwxm3/view?usp=sharing)

My computer certainly isn't a LinusTechTips mega-workstation, but I know my setup well enough to know that it should be plenty powerful enough to handle this workload, so I've already ruled out hardware inadequacies (attempts to render at 720p, 1080p, and 4k with the Viewport Render works fine); but other than that I'm at a bit of a loss for what the problem is. As I said in my intro, I've only done still images up to this point (with an array of different scenes and models), and those have always worked out just fine.

Any advice or suggestions about these issues would be greatly appreciated :D

Comment: can you change the file access on gdrive to "Anyone with the link"?

Comment: @wilks - Okay, link updated.

Comment: Thanks. Everything rendered fine on my computer which has much lower specs than yours (with 2.90 beta). I can only think of a hardware problem like errors on the disk (worth a try rendering to different disk/partition or even to a usb key) or bad ram. Also you could see if upgrading to the latest nvidia's drivers help? Stabs in the dark really

Comment: Okay, so I updated my GPU drivers and tried rendering to my D drive and neither worked, same issues. As a sanity check though, I downloaded the "Hi, I'm Amy" demo from the blender demo page, and it worked perfectly on each of 3 renders (and at different resolutions). At this point my only guess is that there's something about this project that doesn't agree with my computer or project specific settings, I'll work a bit more on it to see what could cause it. At the very least I know that the problem definitely isn't my computer.

Comment: well, that is really weird... Hope you work it out somehow

Comment: Great news, I think I've figured out the problem, it was a badly behaving add-on the whole time!!! Specifically a combo of the spring jiggle/wiggle bone add-ons, I was doing another animation without it and it worked fine; out of interest and curiosity, I turned the wiggle bone addon on and the animation failed. According the the wiggle bone addon docs, it's a known problem and the addon maker recently made a work-around by adding a bake-in-animation feature for the wiggle motion.